# Zend Framework 2 - Static options for annotation form

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, annotations, zend-framework2

I'm using `Docrine2` with `AnnotationForms` and I wonder how I can achieve the following:

I have a field in my Entity which should be a dropdown containing about 4 static choices.

For `Django` users: I want to define `choices`.

Example:

*Label: In which continent do you live?*

*Choices: Africa, Asia, America, Europe*

Because the choices won't change I'd like to put them somewhere in my Entity so they are bound to the data model.

Is there such a possibility? Or if not what would be the best work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by accident [here](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/zend-framework-2-step-by-step-build-form-using-annotation-builder/):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Form\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Select")
 * @Form\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
 * @Form\Options({"label":"Continent*", "value_options": {"0":"Select one","1":"Africa","2":"America"}})
 * @Form\Validator({"name":"InArray", "options":{"haystack":{"1","2"}, "messages":{"notInArray":"Choose one!"}}})
 * @Form\Attributes({"value":"0"})
 */
protected $continent;
```